# Установить выбранным select, зная только содержимое тега

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eсть `select` вида:

```
<select name="project_quick_jump_box" id="project_quick_jump_box" form="add_rule_form">
 <option value="-1">Выбрать проект...</option>
 <option value="100" selected="selected">Входящие обращения</option> 
 <option value="153">Проекты</option>
 <option value="130">&nbsp;&nbsp;» Касса"</option>
</select>
```

Каким образом сделать выбранный элемент в select, зная только содержимое тега? Например, мне известно только значение `"Касса"`, соответственно сделать выбранным:

```
<option value="130">&nbsp;&nbsp;» Касса"</option>
```

Везде находил примеры, как по `value` задать выбранный элемент, но здесь `value` мне не известно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так например

```js
$("#project_quick_jump_box option").each(function() {
  if ($(this).text().indexOf("Касса") >= 0) {
    $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="project_quick_jump_box" id="project_quick_jump_box" form="add_rule_form">
  <option value="-1">Выбрать проект...</option>
  <option value="100" selected="selected">Входящие обращения</option>
  <option value="153">Проекты</option>
  <option value="130">&nbsp;&nbsp;» Касса"</option>
</select>
```